# USB_OTG_FS for stm device not working on linux

Tags: linux, stm32, adafruit, stm32cubeide, minicom

I am using a adafruit STM32F405 feather, and have written a program for it in the stm32cubeide. I have enabled `USB_OTG_FS` and also selected VCP under USB_DEVICE under middleware. I sent a simple message using `CDC_Transmit_FS()` within my `main.c` file. I wanted to then display the message using minicom but the stm32f405 is not recognized as a virtual com port when i plug it in. Please can anyone help with this problem?

This what i get from `dmesg`

```
[13875.812682] CPU4: Package temperature/speed normal
[13875.812714] CPU7: Package temperature/speed normal
[13875.812714] CPU3: Package temperature/speed normal
[13991.385412] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[13991.535289] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0483, idProduct=5740, bcdDevice= 2.00
[13991.535296] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[13991.535299] usb 1-1: Product: STM32 Virtual ComPort
[13991.535302] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: STMicroelectronics
[13991.535305] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 2052368B424D
[13991.537315] cdc_acm 1-1:1.0: ttyACM1: USB ACM device
[14011.512953] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 7
[14011.965421] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[14012.115098] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0483, idProduct=df11, bcdDevice=22.00
[14012.115101] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[14012.115103] usb 1-1: Product: STM32  BOOTLOADER
[14012.115105] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: STMicroelectronics
[14012.115106] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 2052368B424D
[14062.597167] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 8
[14062.905188] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[14078.380920] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[14093.996841] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[14094.232811] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[14109.616762] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[14125.228684] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[14125.336733] usb usb1-port1: attempt power cycle
[14125.752659] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[14130.988679] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[14132.495127] usb 1-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[14132.700624] usb 1-1: device not accepting address 11, error -71
[14142.916583] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[14158.508419] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
```

It appears that there is an error when reading the usb device descripter, any ideas how i can solve this?

Comment: Please include the last few lines of output of `dmesg` command just after you plug your device.

Comment: @Tagli I just update my post to include dmesg, there appears to be a problem reading the usb device descripter. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Apparently, device enumeration fails at the early stages, probably in descriptor fetch. There can be many reasons. I think you can assume that Cube framework is okay. So, I would suspect hardware, or wrong HSE crystal values or wrong clock configuration. BTW, does it run on Windows? I mean, is this problem Linux specific?

Answer (score 0):

HAL_PWREx_EnableUSBVoltageDetector() at end of MX_USB_DEVICE_Init for older Firmware it appears.

I updated from Jan to July release of IDE, MX and STM32CubeF4 releases and my USB_OTG_FS started working (the call above is not present in the latest).

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.